# Can a skip-list have duplicate elements?

Tags: data-structures, duplicates, skip-lists

I know a skip-list is a sorted data structure, but can it have duplicate elements? Or should it be that if you try to insert an element that already exists it will just return the pointer to the preexisting element?

Comment: It can .. see http://www.cs.yorku.ca/~ruppert/Mikhail.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is "yes, a skiplist can have duplicate elements, but it's not required to."

Can you make a skiplist that supports duplicates? Absolutely! You just update the insertion procedure so that if you see the element you're looking for, you just insert the element right after it. It's similar to how you can have a BST that stores multiple equal values - you just have the insertion procedure always go left or always go right when it finds an equal element.

But *must* a skiplist always allow duplicates? No, it doesn't have to, just the same way that not all BSTs allow for duplicates.

If you're using a skiplist library, consult the documentation to see whether it supports duplicates. If you're creating your own, feel free to build it however you'd like, and document your decision.

Comment: Some notes from my experience: I have implemented an indexable skip list with duplicates (absolutely need both properties for my use-case) but I'm hitting bad performance issues for datasets with a high number of duplicates because the links aren't skipping much. I have tried not creating links between node with equal values but it doesn't seem to help much. I'm still investigating how to make it faster, I have a bunch of ideas including an additional pointer giving access to the last occurrence of a value on the last row, in order to skip all duplicates.

Comment: Another untested idea: try to represent the number of duplicates in the distance value contained by the nodes (for implementing random access) and actually insert the values only once, only ever incrementing or decrementing distances.

Comment: Update: the second idea I talked about was the best one. I managed to get pretty fast (1 to 4x slower than the equivalent methods in `TreeSet`, but with random access and duplicates support) insertions, removals and random access. My implementation is here, for your interest: https://github.com/Dicee/algorithmicProblems/blob/master/hackerrank/algorithms/sorting/fraudulentActivityNotifications/SkipListSolutionForFun.scala